# Fitness function for scm distribution

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

Problem: I need a fitness function to be used to determine cost and number of item distributed.

Denote:

I have 1 Distribution Center(DC).

I have 3 Stores (S1, S2, S3)

if for some occurrence of time DC has 30 Pcs of item A. The Stores ask to DC to send them item.
S1 ask for 10 pcs item A.
S2 ask for 15 pcs.
S3 ask for 20 pcs.

How can I determine the optimal number item to send to Store while DC item < total item requested, while profit from the sale of that item in every store is calculated for fitness function?

Example of solution:

- DC send 7  to S1
- DC send 10 to S2
- DC send 13 to S3

What is the best fitness function to be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use a profit measure.
Your fitness function would look like

```
integer fitness(int numberSentToA, int numberSentToB, int numberSentToC){
    moneyEarned = numberSentToA * priceAtWhichABuys + numberSentToB * priceAtWhichBBuys + numberSentToC * priceAtWhichCBuys;
    return moneyEarned;
}
```

However, there is no need to use a genetic algorithm for something like this.
You can find the optimal solution by using the greedy approach.

Sort the stores by the amount at which they buy the goods.
Take the store which is willing to pay the most amount, and send him all the goods he wants.
Then select the next highest paying store.
Do this until you run out of goods, at which point you have the optimal distribution.